# Pressed Status propagation in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view

I have a layout with the following structure:

```
  LinearLayout_1
      ImageView
      TextView
      Linearlayout_2
         ImageView
         TextView
```

Some Views within LinearLayout_1 have padding and margins. I want to set a OnClickListener over LinearLayout_1 (for detecting clicks in the whole layout). But when its pressed I need all the items inside in pressed status. How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. The key is to use

```
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

in the childs of the View where the clicks are listened